# Есть ли альтернатива Spring Security в java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Может есть какая-то более гибкая технология , фреймворк или еще что-то. Пока не нашел особой информации по этому вопросу.

Comment: [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)

Comment: + прямое использование JAASи и встроенные в Java EE механизмы безопасности. Стоит отметить, последняя версия spring security прекрасно понимает Java EE аннотаци.

Comment: HDIV этот библиотека, которая по смыслу напоминает SS, но в нее входит больше возможностей секюрити от хаккинга.